# SQL Server replace NULL value with last value from previous row

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to replace NULL value for each code group using the value before the first Null:

```
code     amount       date
-------------------------------
 A        1500     2013-02-03
 A        1800     2013-03-05
 A        1300        NULL
 A        1300        NULL
 B        1300     2013-05-03
 B        1300     2013-06-01
 B        1300     2013-07-02
 B        1600        NULL
 B        1300        NULL
 C        1200     2014-07-02
 C        1500     2014-08-05
 C        1700        NULL
 C        1100        NULL
 C        1300        NULL
```

In this table, I want to replace `NULL` value for the date for each "code" with last date value for that code. e.g. date for code A should look like this and same for the others.

```
code     amount       date
-----------------------------
 A        1500     2013-02-03
 A        1800     2013-03-05
 A        1300     2013-03-05
 A        1300     2013-03-05
```

I know there are other similar posts for this question, but none of them give me the result above. I guess because selecting last value for each specific code is a bit tricky.

Comment: what is the version of your sql server

Comment: Something like `UPDATE T SET [date] = U.[date] FROM myTable T CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM myTable WHERE code = T.code) U([date]) WHERE T.[date] IS NULL`?

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` `NULL` values in the original table, or write a `SELECT` query that returns the result set without `NULLs`?

Comment: @TheGameiswar it is SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
UPDATE mytable
SET date = date2
FROM mytable o
  CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT MAX(date) date2 FROM mytable i WHERE i.id=o.id group by id) ii
where o.date is null
```